# bash script to sort

Tags: bash

I have this file I created:

```
Kuala Lumpur        78          56
Seoul               86          66
Karachi             95          75
Tokyo               85          60
Lahore              85          75
Manila              90          85
```

On the command line I can sort it no problem using `sort -t` and delimit with a tab space, but now I'm trying to write a script to read this in and print out different sorts. Now if I read into an array and tell it to store by the tab the "Kuala Lumpur" line is thrown off and then, so is the sort. What do i do about that space. I don't want to take it out or replace with a comma but if I have to I will.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cat asiapac-temps | sort -t'    ' -k 1,1d
 echo ""
 cat asiapac-temps | sort -t'    ' -k 2,2n
 echo ""
 cat asiapac-temps | sort -t'    ' -k 3
```

this is what I'm using now. I was trying to do this in a different way so to not use `sort` over and over
The output is:
By city:

```
   Karachi             95          75
   Kuala Lumpur        78          56
   Lahore              85          75
   Manila              90          85
   Seoul               86          66
   Tokyo               85          60
```

by high temp (col2)

```
   Kuala Lumpur        78          56
   Lahore              85          75
   Tokyo               85          60
   Seoul               86          66
   Manila              90          85
   Karachi             95          75
```

by low temp (col3)

```
   Kuala Lumpur        78          56
   Tokyo               85          60
   Seoul               86          66
   Karachi             95          75
   Lahore              85          75
   Manila              90          85
```

Comment: There are other options for `sort`, like `--key`. `man sort` and find out if any of them are useful for you.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs yes but how to read in the lines of the file and then sort them?

Comment: `man sort` will tell you that `sort` accepts one or more files. It will also tell you that without any files, or when the file is `-`, that `sort` will read from standard in.

Comment: if you're talking `sort -k 1,1d` that space in Kuala Lumpur is still a problem especially when you try to sort the nums

Comment: `man sort` will tell you that `--key` will read the key from a start position to an end position, which means that the spaces are not a problem. Have you opened `man sort` yet?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs So what you're saying is I don't need to read in line by line? Just pass `sort` the file? If so that would be amazing

Comment: I did that on the command line `sort -k 1 asiapac-temps` The script would just have multiple calls to sort with different options. I was trying to do it another way

Comment: I can't figure out what you're talking about. It sounds like you're asking how to do what sort clearly and easily does. Can you update your question to show some expected output to go with your posted sample input to help us understand the problem?

Comment: @healix "I was trying to do this in a different way so to not use sort over and over"... Just use sort.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do but you say you want to produce sorted output without using sort, right? You could read it into an array in GNU awk and use asort() or asorti() or create other arrays of the ordered indices for each column but it really sounds like you have some agenda in mind that so far you haven't shared with us so it's hard to provide suggestions. By the way, lose the UUOC.

Comment: @EdMorton yes, thats right. I want to read it into an array and run a loop over it with different sort options. Unless I can use sort just once and output 3 different sorts of the same file, in which case I don't know how. I think thats what Rein is getting at. No agenda just feel like an array would work too.Just unsure how to preserve spacing so to sort

Comment: You can't sort anything once and output 3 different results. Any time you write a loop in shell you've probably got the wrong approach (shell is primarily an environment from which to call tools, not a programming language). Just calling sort each time you want to produce sorted output will almost certainly be simpler and more efficient than any approach you can come up with involving array indexing.

Comment: @EdMorton yeah, I just came to that conclusion. Thanks for all the help. I guess I'm just used to arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

You can't sort anything once and output 3 different results. Any time you write a loop in shell you've probably got the wrong approach (shell is primarily an environment from which to call tools, not a programming language). Just calling sort each time you want to produce sorted output will almost certainly be simpler and more efficient than any approach you can come up with involving array indexing. – Ed Morton

Comment: Good answer, even though I disagree that _shell is [...] is not a programming language_. What is the definition of a programming language, and where does bash fail to fulfill parts of this definition? bash is even Turing complete...

Comment: Good point, however, as I read it, Ed Morton actually wrote _shell is primarily [...] not a programming language_.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "how do I input the tab character from the command line", the answer is "you don't need to" -- sort recognizes the tab character as a separator by default.